# Mobile music app (integrating a music player) first in android and ios later

Tags: android, ios, templates, audio-player, android-music-player

I am a student android developer whose annual project is to develop a music application integrating a music player.

my concerns are as follows:
Do you have any basic projects (especially those that already incorporate a music player or template) on git that could help me continue this development?

thank's.

Comment: head over to Github, & search for a Music Player... :)

Comment: You will find load of them on github

Answer (score 0):

Go here and don't forget to accept my answer. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-project-setup--mobile-22764